# How can I switch two capacitors from parallel to series?

Tags: capacitor, switches, series

I am trying to find out how many poles I will need in a switch to switch the circuit from A to B:

[image]

I was able to do it with 4 switches. Is there a simpler solution?

[image]

Comment: Circuitlab is supposed to include the schematic here without the need to post screenshots when you click "save and insert" in the top right corner.

Comment: Anyway, what you are asking doesn't make much sense. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? Is it a real one or just some artificial homework assignment?

Comment: It suppose to charge both caps to 2V5 and after switching get 5V output. It is not a homework. I need to get a temporarily "hard" source from poor battery.

Comment: Caps can't magically raise the voltage...

Comment: @Lundin that's why the switches are there... [Voltage doubler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler#Switched_capacitor_circuits)

Comment: @Arsenal And as explained in that link, switches and caps alone won't solve anything. You need a clock.

Answer (score 3):

The classic switched capacitor voltage doubler uses 3 SPDT switches and has the basic configuration as below. The switch could technically be a single 3PDT type.
.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOfGUn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's a great circuit diagram and explanation.  The blue lines and the charge/discharge arrows, and your mention of a 3PDT switch, are what makes it obvious to me what's going on: charge in parallel, discharge in series.  Makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept that R1 keeps charging C1 (which will only increase the duration during which you get a "high enough" voltage), then you can use only 2 switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSSAq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NB: the C1 will be more charged that C2 during discharge (or during charge if you don't let enough time to recharge it fully).

If you really need to disconnect R1, then you need a 3rd switch.

A completely different solution would be to use a boost converter (2.5V -> 5V) with current limiting capability (ie not shutting down when in overcurrent, but limiting voltage or chopping instead), and put a single capacitor at the output. It might be better, or worse, depending on your precise application

Comment: An ingenious solution!