# How does this voltage doubler obtain a higher voltage output than the input of 5 V?

Tags: voltage, ltspice, simulation

I've designed a basic schematic using a 5 V AC source.

[image]

Upon simulating this circuit, I observed that the voltage between D1 and C3 registers at +9.55 V, while between C4 and D4, it measures at -9.55 V.

[image]

This raised my curiosity about how it's possible to obtain a higher voltage output than the input of 5 V. I also wonder what would occur if we introduce a load to the circuit – would the measured voltage decrease?

Comment: *I also wonder what would occur if we introduce a load to the circuit – would the measured voltage decrease?* <-- you have a simulator so, go for it.

Comment: @Andyaka Yep, tested it and voltage was reduced significally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a voltage doubler circuit. Doubling a voltage is what a voltage doubler does.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler

"A voltage doubler is an electronic circuit which charges capacitors from the input voltage and switches these charges in such a way that, in the ideal case, exactly twice the voltage is produced at the output as at its input."

A voltage doubler is one type of converter. converters change from one voltage to another. This particular converter changes 5 Vpp AC to 10 V DC and -10 V DC.

Comment: If you take just the doubler part on its own, it's more of an AC-DC converter--you need to couple it with an oscillator to make it a dc-dc converter.

Answer (score 13):

## Basic idea

It is extremely simple and intuitive - **to charge a capacitor by a voltage source and then to add the capacitor voltage to the source   voltage**. In accordance with the schematic below:

1. Charge a capacitor C1- by connecting it in parallel to a negative voltage source V1- ("-" means "during the negative half wave).
2. Connect the charged capacitor (presented as a rechargeable battery C1+) in series to an equivalent but positive voltage source V1+ so that to sum their voltages (- +, - +).
3. Connect this battery of two voltage sources in series to another capacitor C2 in parallel to charge it with the doubled voltage Vout = 10 V.

Thus, first the source voltage is copied; then, the sum of the source voltage and its copy is copied and applied to the load. The need for such "double copying" comes from the fact that the source voltage and accordingly, the voltage sum, oscillate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB4K8E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have considered this idea in detail in [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/480518/61398) to a related question. It is so simple that we can even manually implement it as shown in [How can I switch two capacitors from parallel to series?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/684134/61398)

## Emulated capacitors

I have illustrated this idea in the conceptual CircuitLab schematics below by replacing the capacitors by voltage sources. This gives us the opportunity to explore circuit operation through the unique *DC Live Simulation* without worrying about time.

### V1 < 0; V2 > 0

When we close SW2 and SW3, the voltage source C1 copies the voltage of the negative voltage source V1, and C2 copies the voltage of the positive voltage source V2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frEVqE.png)</sup>

### V1 > 0; V2 < 0

The two sources then reverse their polarity, and we open SW2 and SW3, and close SW1 and SW4. As a result, C1's and C2's voltages are added to V1's and V2's voltages. The resulting voltages are applied to the output sources C3 and C4.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk3bxx.png)</sup>

### Unipolar voltage doubler...

In real doublers, the conceptual switches are implemented by *diode switches* that are controlled by the input voltage polarity. I have used "ideal" diodes (with VF = 0 V) so as not to deviate from the main idea with such details as VF.

**... with positive output voltage...**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKiIzR.png)</sup>

When applying an AC input voltage Vin...

[image: STEP 3_1_1_1]

... the capacitors cannot instantaneously (for one half-wave) charge. They are charged gradually over several consecutive half-waves until Vc1 finally reaches 5 V...

[image: STEP 3_1_2]

...Vc3 reaches 10 V...

[image: STEP 3_1_3]

... and the ripple voltage tends to zero.

**... with negative output voltage**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHjyNL.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3_2_1]

[image: STEP 3_2_2]

Now Vc4 finally reaches -10 V.

[image: STEP 3_2_3]

### Bipolar voltage doubler...

We quickly guessed that it was enough to connect only one input source to the inputs of both doublers. We also connect the two grounds and get the complete circuit of a bipolar voltage doubler.

**... unloaded...**

As you can see, when there is no load connected, the ripple voltage is small, and tends to zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZGmrU.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3_3]

**... loaded**

When we connect even a not very heavy load (30 kΩ)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKMocx.png)</sup>

... the ripple voltage significantly increases.

[image: STEP 3_4]

The remedy can be to increase the capacitances C1 and C2. This will increase the startup time.

## See also

[How do we explain the voltage doubler operation by analogy?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/483061/61398)

[How does the voltage doubler work at the startup?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/482987/61398)

Answer (score 8):

> *How does this voltage doubler obtain a higher voltage output than the
> input of 5 V?*

Actually, your input voltage is 10 volts p-p and, what you have formed is a circuit that clamps the most negative part of that waveform to around -0.5 volts (C1 and D2) and then rectifies and smooths it with D1 and C3. This makes a positive DC output of slightly less than 10 volts.

Then, you have duplicated that circuit but, that duplicated circuit clamps the most positive part of the input waveform to around +0.5 volts (C2 and D3) then rectifies and smooths the resulting negative peak to about -9.5 volts using D4 and C4.

You would get better results with a square wave input of course and that's quite a common thing to do when trying to generate a local negative power rail from a positive supply voltage. You can also stack these circuits and get even more voltage magnification.

> *I also wonder what would occur if we introduce a load to the circuit –
> would the measured voltage decrease?*

Yes it would and you'd see more ripple voltage. Nevertheless they are very useful especially when the current is low and you need high voltage magnification.

Comment: "Yes it would and you'd see more ripple voltage. Nevertheless they are very useful especially when the current is low and you need high voltage magnification. " - Yes, i simulated this circuit but this time with load and did observed the behavior you mentioned. Thank you very much!

Comment: @T1P0Z if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 4):

LTSpice is a great, accurate and free simulator. But what it doesn't do so well is show the dynamic behavior in the circuit, at least directly.

First, let's look at your signal source. The SINE(0 5 1000) statement generates a 5V AC at 1kHz with an offset of zero. You've grounded one side of it, so the + side swings from +5 to -5V. That's a swing of 10V, not 5.

Second, your doubler(s). Yep, that's what they do... double. Each one is a half-wave doubler, which work by 'stacking' the AC voltage with the steering diodes.

The resulting no-load output voltages from the doublers will be their peak input, minus a couple of diode drops. So for the positive wave we have 2 x 5V minus the drops, or 9.5-ish volts. For the negative wave, -9.5-ish.

Let's visualize it using Falstad ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9ETIkJAFgGZqBTAWjDACgA3cdScTcmF4hsNPnwhg41KLJgJ2AYxGRUPPqInDxseJAjMa0VHUiYaCTMToIaucjDgdl2VSBvYRY9wk869+iBGJnQCdug0RGRSSI767ADu6iII5IRpqVCJyWACOdrZQloSRJ5FWUlgpTnVHhXgtb4qanWQhdXlrmrlbZXCmsnpWQAmKWneQ1WeZQByNGA0qNkDnZk9y2v9a9W9Y14amUO7Q3R0GeStG+d72KhqbaMnZzd3IuBzC0tJA3UnTQ8iV7lOiuQbveaLdijEF8X6vX7gz5XHzTeH-ZZAraCArKOpTFH7OS6eAQIjQdARGzoMCoSxESBYKhxZwE24tJqnBxQYlOEBkimYOgWXKnSA0HD3XQcJJ1TkEy4yjkc0EKm6ZX6ZXa-bwahzZXWs15apr4vEFRVlYQw5LG6bq1A0PZtADm7gdezo7rwfnqZth7vWFvl7suZxaAeE9Et4iyYbdjrqUYJ4nYAHtZBFZGIiFRYjyiAJUoRZD66GmfCBM3xs1QpOBsMZwG8bO5y88q0FIDnwBIG91mxdyzTK47q13a-54AX0EWkNNwC12EA)):

[image]

You can see the doubling action on each half-cycle as it is happening, especially if you 'reset' the sim and watch it charging up the caps. (I slowed it down to 100Hz to make it easier to follow.)

A note: the forward diode drop of 'D1' (upper right) is quite low (only 0.16V) because the forward current is next to zero. Add a load, and this increases some as well as causing the voltage to droop between cycles.

Answer (score 0):

In reality where ground is 0v I dont see why we would get much over a volt for either polarity since both would just be a diode off ground. No? This circuit seems invalid in real life. Let me explain, positive going signal would be shorted to ground through D3 and the negative going signal shorted through D2. Why isnt this the case?

What you would want is a diode before each cap to block the opposite polarity.